# How to summarize by row and specific value of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run a query to a table to get sums per a specific field value.

```
rechargedate    originid
------------------------
2015-02-02      3
2015-02-02      3
2015-02-02      1
2015-02-02      1
2015-02-02      3
2015-02-02      2
2015-02-01      2
2015-02-01      3
2015-02-01      1
2015-02-01      1
2015-02-01      2
```

And the query result should be like:

```
rechargedate    orig1   orig2   orig3
-------------------------------------
2015-02-02      2       1       3
2015-02-01      2       2       1
```

How can I accomplish that with MS SQL 2008?

Comment: What have toot tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    RechargeDate    DATE,
    OriginID        INT
)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('2015-02-02', 3),('2015-02-02', 3),('2015-02-02', 1),
('2015-02-02', 1),('2015-02-02', 3),('2015-02-02', 2),
('2015-02-01', 2),('2015-02-01', 3),('2015-02-01', 1),
('2015-02-01', 1),('2015-02-01', 2);

SELECT
    RechargeDate,
    orig1 = SUM(CASE WHEN OriginID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    orig2 = SUM(CASE WHEN OriginID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    orig3 = SUM(CASE WHEN OriginID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #temp
GROUP BY RechargeDate
ORDER BY RechargeDate DESC

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**RESULT**

```
RechargeDate orig1       orig2       orig3
------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
2015-02-02   2           1           3
2015-02-01   2           2           1
```

Comment: Awesome wewesthemenace! Exactly what I was looking for, and so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `PIVOT`. Check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to learn `PIVIOT` in `SQL SERVER.`

```
SELECT rechargedate, 
       [1] AS orig1,
       [2] AS orig2,
       [3] AS orig3 
FROM #TEST
PIVOT(COUNT(originid) FOR originid IN([1],[2],[3])) AS Piv
ORDER BY rechargedate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Kumar, I tried the Wewe solution as it is similar to what I was trying and worked like a charm. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create the columns you want with a CASE statement and then do a sum, eg,

```
SELECT rechargedate,
     SUM(CASE WHEN originid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orig1,
     SUM(CASE WHEN originid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orig2,
     SUM(CASE WHEN originid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orig3
FROM {your_table}
GROUP BY rechargedate
ORDER BY rechargedate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you evanv, it is close, but not exactly. It was also my solution. I get some zeros in the result set.